# border-left in css when % is used for width not working

Tags: css, html, border

I have this piece of HTML5 code:

```
<div id="box4">
  <div id="leftSide"></div>
  <div id="rightSide"></div>
</div>
```

And in this CSS code to add style:

```css
#box4 {
   width:100%;
   height:80%;
   background-color: gray;
   float:left;
}
#leftSide { width: 50%;}
#rightSide { left: 50%; width: 50%; border-left: 1px solid #cdd0d4;}
#leftSide, #rightSide {position:absolute}
```

However, the border-left is not showing for the "rightSide" `<div>` tag.
I think it is related to the fact that I am using the % for the width of this tag, but I don't know how to solve it. I need to use the % as the width size. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This happend because there is no text in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works. The problem is both `leftSide` and `rightSide` elements don't have any height. If you set a `height` for it, or add some content you'll see.

```css
#box4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
}
#leftSide { width: 50%;}
#rightSide { left: 50%; width: 50%; border-left: 1px solid #cdd0d4;}
#leftSide, #rightSide { position:absolute; }
```

```html
<div id="box4">
  <div id="leftSide">1</div>
  <div id="rightSide">2</div>
</div>
```

Other than that, you should set `#box4 {position: relative;}`, otherwise the the absolute children will be positioned relative the viewport (however, maybe it's OK for the current case).

And to have the `height: 80%;` to work, you'll need to set `html, body {height: 100%;}`, that is how percentage height works. See the updated example below.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; }
#box4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#leftSide, #rightSide {
  height: 100%;
}
#leftSide { width: 50%;}
#rightSide { left: 50%; width: 50%; border-left: 1px solid #cdd0d4;}
#leftSide, #rightSide { position:absolute; }
```

```html
<div id="box4">
  <div id="leftSide">1</div>
  <div id="rightSide">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I add content later using JavaScript, but I want a vertical line between "leftSide" and "rightSide" div tags with a height equal to height of "box4" right from the beginning.

Comment: @TJ1 I updated it with the details and a demo, hope that answers all.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. Yes it did work, however I had to set the height of the "rightSide" to %79 not %80 otherwise the boarder would be larger than box4, any idea what that is?

Comment: You're welcome. Have you noticed I also added `box-sizing` property there?